# Trying to scrape monthly rent data available on a estate website using selenium python, But getting the price entry of only 1st propery in repetition

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am working on a project to collect the the  data of monthly rent of a rental property available in my area through a website 99acres.  I am using selenium for this purpose.

while abstracting the data i  am getting the rent value of 1st property shown on the web page again  and again. I am trying to run a loop to abstract the monthly rent data. Here is my code file. It will be a great help if someone just let me know the correct way to abstract the data.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service



chrome_driver_path = "/home/dibyanshu/study/development/chromedriver"
service = Service(chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.maximize_window()

rent_99acres_link = "https://www.99acres.com/search/property/rent/delhi-ncr?city=1&preference=R&area_unit=1&budget_min=0&res_com=R&isPreLeased=N"

driver.get(rent_99acres_link)
time.sleep(2)

#setting up max rent limit t 40000
maxrent_limit_scroller = driver.find_element(by="id", value="bdf__lf_budMax")
maxrent_limit_scroller.click()
time.sleep(2)
all_max_price_list = driver.find_elements(by="id", value="lf_budget_max_list")
time.sleep(2)
max_limit_40000 = driver.find_element(by="xpath", value="//*[@id='lf_budget_max_list']/li[33]")
max_limit_40000.click()
time.sleep(2)

#Sorting by low to high
sort_by = driver.find_element(by="xpath", value="//*[@id='sortby']/div/div/div")
sort_by.click()
sort_by_lowtohigh = driver.find_element(by="xpath", value="//*[@id='sortby']/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/span")
sort_by_lowtohigh.click()
time.sleep(2)


#collecting monthly rent for all vailable properties on the screen
all_rent_monthly = driver.find_elements(by="class name", value="tupleCardWrap")

for element in all_rent_monthly:
    price = element.find_element(by="xpath", value="//*[@id='srp_tuple_price']")
    print(price.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`.`** in the Xpath while finding an element with in an element.

Below is the code for the same.

```
# Imports for Explicit waits
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

driver.get("https://www.99acres.com/search/property/rent/delhi-ncr?city=1&preference=R&area_unit=1&budget_min=0&res_com=R&isPreLeased=N")

elements_list = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@data-label='SEARCH']/section")))

for element in elements_list:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element)
    price = element.find_element(By.XPATH,".//td[@id='srp_tuple_price']")
    address = element.find_element(By.XPATH,".//div[@id='srp_tuple_description']/div").text
    print(price.text)
    print(address)
    print(price.text)
```

**Output**

```
₹ 30,000 /month
This 3 bhk flat in sector 104 gurgaon is available in ats triumph for rent, one of the most prominent projects for residential flats in gurgaon. Property has attached 4 bathrooms & more than 3 balconies with 3 rooms. The flat consists of 3 bedrooms, built on 2290 sq.Ft. A separate space for servant room is available in this flat. Society provides 1 covered parking with this flat & the option fo...

₹ 14,500 /month
Deposit 1 month(s) rent
Situated in sector 88 faridabad faridabad, srs residency is a well planned, ready to move society that offers a pleasant living experience to its residents. This is a 2 bhk apartment now available for rent. This property is close to metro station, close to school, close to hospital and close to market. Property has attached 2 bathrooms & more than 3 balconies with 2 rooms set in 1098 sq.Ft. Car...

₹ 45,000 /month
Deposit 2 month(s) rent
This is located in a gated society . There is a private garden and also spacious interiors inside. The address is: C-26 south city ii, gurugram, haryana. House is built on 360 square yard plot. Ground floor: On ground floor it has 3 bedrooms , 3 full bath, one large family room hall, one large formal living room, store room, a big kitchen. There is a garden in front, backyard porch and a big dr...
...
```

Comment: can you please clarify one more thing!, I am tying to get hold on the address and the link of the property using this element_list only but when i am runing the code it gives following error: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='srp_tuple_description']"} althogh it is working fine for getting price data using xpath. can you please help me to find the reason behind this error.

Comment: @DibyanshuPandey - For the locator mentioned in the comment, I have updated the code. Have used Xpath - `.//div[@id='srp_tuple_description']/div` for address. Not sure which is the link element you are trying to extract.

Comment: @pmadu sorry to trouble you again. getting same error:

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//div[@id='srp_tuple_description']/div"}

Comment: @pmadu After adding sleep time in between its working.